# Is there a "Hover to click" feature in Gnome Taskbar?

Tags: gnome, taskbar

Does GNOME have a feature that allows me to hover over a window on the taskbar and select it without clicking? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is no such feature for the gnome-panel specifically.

However there is an option in gnome's accessibility settings, so that hovering anywhere for a specific (configurable) amount of time, will cause a click. Depending on your needs, this may be helpful to you.